# gitで大容量のコミットをpushするとき

Tags: git

今までgit管理していなかったサイトをgit管理することにし、
自前のgitlabにpushしようとしたのですが、
以下のようなエラーが出てしまいました。

```
$ git push origin master:master
Counting objects: 21810, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (21810/21810), done.
error: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 413B | 177.00 KiB/s   
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Writing objects: 100% (21810/21810), 1.00 GiB | 21.07 MiB/s, done.
Total 21810 (delta 4024), reused 0 (delta 0)
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

容量は1.2GBほどあり、
一気にpushしたせいでエラーがでてしまったのかと思うのですが、
これを解決する方法はないでしょうか。

Answer (score 4):

大きなファイルを一度`git`の管理フォルダから外してからステージングしなおしてはどうでしょうか？

また基本的にバイナリファイルなどを取り扱うことは`git`は苦手なため、大きなバイナリファイルがあるのであれば`git-lfs`を使うことをおすすめします。

https://git-lfs.github.com/

Answer (score 1):

トランスポートに HTTP を使っていて 413 が返されているのなら、それはやはり送信しようとするデータのサイズがサーバにとって大きすぎるということです。

GitLab のセットアップの詳細が不明なのでわかりませんが、例えば nginx をフロントエンドサーバにしているのなら、次のような設定をすれば改善するかもしれません。

```
client_max_body_size 2g;
```

あるいは、送信データサイズの制限がない SSH のようなトランスポートを使うのがよいかと思います。